# What depth level should I set in httrack?

Tags: http, web-scraping, web-crawler, httrack

I am trying to clone the website: https://www.classcentral.com/ using httrack. I only want to get the main page and the pages of the links belonging to that main page.
How should I set "Max Depth" and "Maximum external depth" for this purpose? I have tried different ways and it doesn't work for me. Apparently putting 2 and 2, it works, but I had been trying to download the pages for three hours and nothing ends, I don't know what could be happening.

Answer (score 1):

there. It's called 'One Level Deep'. You have to select 'Download Website(s)' in action section. It'd work. I've done this one time. Happy Coding. Attaching a screenshot[select 'download website(s)'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R8UV.png)